# How to read CPU usage statistics shown in "top" screen?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, centos6

I'm pretty confused about understanding of CPU usage in a linux server...

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

WHAT does `Cpu(s): 9.1%us` mean ACTUALLY?

and

WHAT does `74.7` at the ruby/deployer row mean ACTUALLY?

Thank you

Comment: For more general, and useful, understanding of the information you get from top, see: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4285.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have more than one CPU on your machine.

Your process uses 74.7% of one of your CPU. But on line 3, it's a percentage of all your CPUs (0 to 100%, whatever the number of CPU you have on this machine).

If a process used 150%, it would mean this process uses 100% of one CPU and the half of a second one but on line 3, with 2 CPU, you would have 75% of use.

PS: while you execute top, you can press f and select additional info like "Last used CPU". So you could see on which CPU your processes are used.

Comment: It's a virtual machine having 8 cores. So you say that process is consuming 75% of one of the cores?

Comment: Exactly and with a simple cross multiplication you can see how it's possible.
amount of one cpu used = total amount of CPU * CPUs load / 100 = 0.728 (72.8%)

But obviously, all processes are not only on one process.